# Timeseries Plot Fails in Pandas 0.21 (OverflowError)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

On Pandas 0.21 and matplotlib version 2.1, I can no longer plot timeseries dataframes.

I get an OverflowError error from within matplotlib:

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
        255     ix = int(x)
    --> 256     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
        257 
        258     remainder = float(x) - ix

    OverflowError: signed integer is less than minimum
```

I even get this error when I run the simple [Visualization](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) sample :

```
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()
ts.plot()
```

I guess I must have stumbled somewhere after I recently upgraded my pip packages ... Can anyone kindly suggest a fix ?
Prior to this version plotting was fine ....

Update:
Work-around fix (as discussed [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9610)) is to add the following lines

```
from pandas.tseries import converter
converter.register()
```

Comment: I would guess this is not at all your fault. The code runs fine with pandas 0.20.1 and it might be [this issue here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9610) that causes some trouble.

Comment: If you run this in ipython you can use %debug and tell us the value of `ix`.

Comment: ix = 1509980040466200064

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18322) may be similar and has a workaround included.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback which pointed me in the right direction for a work-around fix.
In summary:

Comment: Thanks for your feedback which pointed me in the right direction for a work-around fix.

In summary:

1. Pandas 0.21 introduced an intentional change not to import matplotlib when pandas is imported.

2. This change had (unforseen) implications with the conversion/handling of datetime64 values when plotting a pandas Series.

3. The work-around which fixes the issue is:
    from pandas.tseries import converter
    converter.register()

4. More details on the issue are here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9610